# Stanford cs106b C++ library in XCode 8

Tags: c++, xcode

I am right now trying to solve the exercises of the free [cs106b](https://see.stanford.edu/Course/CS106B/) class, but cannot succeed to setup the needed libraries. I am new to C++ and not that experienced in XCode. I tried to to directly copy the library files I found on [Github] into my XCode project. I tried now for hours to get this package working but it seems they have to be installed in a special way.

I would be glad if somebody could give me some references on how to install a C++ library in XCode, especially the library given by Stanford.

P.S. with the "old" class I was given an .pkg installer, which I installed but did not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help much with the XCode IDE. I have personally completed the course myself; however I used QT creator. The CS106B or CS106X official website (version 2016) provides very good documentation about how someone can go about and get started. http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106b//handouts/qt-creator.html

A point to note: I used the SEE CS106B videos (the online cs106B) to complete the 2016 CS106X course. Please have a look around for the assignment files, in the official cs106B/cs106X website. In case you cannot find it, let me know, I can send it to you. I hope this helps.

Comment: I am also using the SEE CS106B Video lectures and already considered changing to QT Creator. I think I'll give it another try to get it working in XCode tomorrow otherwise I'll change the IDE.

Comment: One pointer! These assignments take a while to do. But when you do, you feel so so so good. All the best. Enjoy CS106.